# Isometries between Lipschitz function spaces

Tags: analysis, continuity

How can I show that $t\mapsto K(x-a)$ is an isometry from the space of $K$-Lipschitz functions $f$ on $[a,b]$ such that $f(0)=0$ and the space of $1$-Lipschitz functions on $[0,K(b-a)]$ such that $f(0)=0$ wrt the $||\, \cdot \, ||_{\infty} $ norm?

Comment: Simplify and suppose that $a=0$ (you can work out when $a\not =0$ but the idea is the same), maybe that makes it easier

Comment: Yes, my problem is actually the interpretation: what inequality do I have to prove?